# Issue on adding an event to iOS Calendar by comparing dates Swift 3

Tags: nsdate, swift3, ios10, xcode8

I've just updated one of my apps to Xcode 8 - Swift 3, and now I get a wired issue while trying to add an event that has a start and end date. Here's the code:

```
@IBAction func addToCalButt(_ sender: AnyObject) {
let eventStore = EKEventStore()

switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: EKEntityType.event) {
case .authorized: insertEvent(eventStore)
case .denied: print("Access denied")
case .notDetermined:

eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: { (granted, error) -> Void in
    if granted { self.insertEvent(eventStore)
    } else { print("Access denied")  }
})

default: print("Case Default")
   }
}


func insertEvent(_ store: EKEventStore) {

    let calendars = store.calendars(for: EKEntityType.event) 

  for calendar in calendars {

        if calendar.title == "Calendar" {
            // Get Start and End dates
            let startDate = eventObj[EVENTS_START_DATE] as! Date
            let endDate = eventObj[EVENTS_END_DATE] as! Date


            // Create Event
            let event = EKEvent(eventStore: store)
            event.title = "\(eventObj[EVENTS_TITLE]!)"
            event.startDate = startDate
            event.endDate = endDate
            event.calendar = calendar

            if startDate < endDate {
                print("less")
            } else {
                print("more")
            }


            // Save Event in Calendar
            do {
                try store.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
                simpleAlert("This Event has been added to your iOS Calendar")

            } catch {
                print("ERROR SAVING EVENT TO CAL: \(error)")
            }


            print("startDate: \(startDate) \endDate: \(endDate)")
        }
}
```

}

and here's the console message:

**more**

**ERROR SAVING EVENT TO CAL: Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=4 "The start date must be before the end date." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The start date must be before the end date.}**

**startDate: 2106-09-20 12:00:00 PM +0000**

**endDate: 2016-09-22 12:00:00 AM +0000**

As you can see the start date is earlier than the end date, so I really can't understand what's wrong in there :(

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it seems like your start date is in 2106 and your end date is 2016

Comment: omg, i was too tired to notice that difference, thanks @Dustin :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Dustin Spengler says, the **startDate** has **2106** as year, while the **endDate** has **2016**, so of course Xcode is right :)